# Routes only for selected group of Resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In my project I have the pages model. In this model i have the following methods to retrieve objects from database:

```
def self.published
  where('published_at <= ?', Date.today ).where('publication_end >= ?', Date.today).where(status: "published")
end
def self.unpublished
  where('published_at > ? or status = ? or publication_end <=', Date.today, "unpublished", Date.today)
end
```

And my question is: It is possible to set in rails routing to have routes only for published pages or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I undestand You, but You can have somenthing like that:

```
resources :pages do
  collection do
    get 'published'
    get 'unpublished'
  end
end
```

Thus You'll have pages/published and pages/unpublished routes.

If You want to check if page status is 'published', You can do it in your show acction:

```
@page = Page.find(param[:id])
if @page.status != 'published'
  redirect_to .....
end
```

However, a better way is to place above code in a "before filter".

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for reply. This is not exactly what i want. I will try explain it in other words.
So in my databse i have 2 pages objects:

1: id:1, name: "Published", status: "published"
2: id:2, name: "Unpublished", status: "unpublished"

And I have in my routes:
resources :pages

and now i can access in my browser pages/1 and pages/2 and it will show me this pages.
My goal is to only can visit published pages. So when i visit pages/2 it will redirect me back.

Comment: I added few lines to my answer.